# extract text from txt file in linux using grep when there is ambguity

Tags: linux, bash, awk, grep

I have a file named l.txt which have follwoing data, first name and last name. When I pass the first name, output should be last name. Below query is working for me .

l.txt

```
name Tony Mcgill
name Jag John
name Jagmohan Singh
```

It works well for name tony. but when I search for jag it gives two results, John & Singh. But I need John only. How can I achieve this.

```
grep -e '^'"name jag" l.txt | awk '{print $3}'
```

I am using this command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `grep -w` to match a word:

```
grep -iw 'tony' file
name Tony Mcgill
```

Alternatively use word boundary in your `grep`:

```
grep -i '\<tony\>' file
```

OR:

```
grep -i '\btony\b' file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do everything in [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk '$2~/\<Jag\>/ {print $3}' l.txt
```

Comment: `$2=="Jag"` is simpler.